# Java will not run in Chromium, Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: 11.10, java, google-chrome, chromium

I am having major issues with Ubuntu and [Kubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu) with regards to Java on websites using Chromium, Google Chrome or Firefox.

I have tried everything to install Java, but it's not happening. Ubuntu 10.10 is fine, but the new [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29) will not run Java. Can anyone provide a step-by-step way to install Java?

- Installing `icedtea-plugin` doesn't work

Comment: Java plugin don't work in x64 Ubuntu :(

Answer (score 10):

```
cd /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so libnpjp2.so
```

Restart chromium-browser.

Or if you have the latest 64-bit version (installed in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/`) use this as the second command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so libnpjp2.so
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it's not working as expected. I tried testing it [here](http://javatester.org/version.html). The browser does recognize the plugin and asks if I want to enable it (only this time or trust the website). However, the area where the applet should appear remains greyed out, and the applet does not seem to be running. Using jre1.7.0_09 here.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install openjre-6-jre icedtea6-plugin
```

should be enough to pass the Java test here: http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp in Chromium. Firefox is a different issue.

However, I am still stuck on some other issues. `openjdk-7-jre` would be preferred, but there is no `icedtea7` yet in Oneiric universe. So on the JDK side, when I use

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I will get the error

> "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for -javaplugin.so."

Comment: you can do ``sudo apt-get install openjre-7-jre icedtea-7-plugin``

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

This worked for me in Kubuntu 11.10 to get JAVA working on the computer; however, it still does not get JAVA to work in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: It's said in the question that installing that package is not working. And that doesn't solve Chrome and Firefox issue

Comment: This worked fine in Ubuntu 13.10 - Google Chrome V:32.0.1700.77 (Official Build 244503)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Java plugin not working in Chromium or Firefox. I use the Oracle JDK's for Java 6 and 7.

Oddly enough, after playing around and not finding any solution that worked, I disabled the plugin in Chromium, and the re-enabled it again - and the Java plugin works, in both Chromium AND Firefox.

I did end up with Chromium not shutting down properly, but after shutting down these processes, it started normally, and the Java plugin still worked. Weird or what?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found, (none of these suggestions worked for me), is as followings:
First install Icedtead pluging by:

- 1) `sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin`

Then in your chrome browser go to:

- 2) chrome-> Settings-> Show Advanced Settings-> Privacy then click on
  Content Settings -> Plug-ins then click on Disable Individual Plug-in
- 3) Disable both "**IceTea-Web Plugin**" and "**Java(TM)**"
- 4) Restart the browser.
- 5) chrome-> Settings-> Show Advanced Settings-> Privacy then click on
  Content Settings -> Plug-ins then click on Disable Individual Plug-in
- 6) Enable **only** "**IceTea-Web Plugin**"
- 7) Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

To get Java working in the browser

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that first, but still no plugin... so.... I tried adding the Natty repository:                                          deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner                deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner                 and looked for the SUN-JAVA6-PLUGIN.  This seemed to have sorted it, though JAVA does not seem to run so well in Kubuntu... thanks though for your help

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747789/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat

Comment: and this: http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/s/sun-java6/

Comment: lastly this: http://www.multimediaboom.com/how-to-install-java-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-ppa/

Answer (score -1):

Install Oracle (Sun) Java JRE by hand:
http://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java

Easy to do, just requires precision in applying the how-to. :-)